# Schedule jobs with at or crontab on Mac OS X and some alternatives

Tags: macos

Using the command line of Mac OS X system, are `at` and `crontab` the correct utilities to use to schedule jobs/processes/scripts? Especially my own scripts.sh?

I am aware that both `at` and `crontab` (actually I am not sure about `crontab`) comes installed by default with Mac OS X but I have this feeling that I need to use something else in order to have it work properly on a Mac OS X system.  Of course I am aware of third party application/software/mdm etc. but I am interested with what comes installed by default inside the Mac OS X.

Comment: `at` and `cron` are both installed by default. `cron` is technically deprecated, but works fine. `at` has not worked for the past several versions of macOS and I haven't been able to get it to work despite trying several suggestions found online. But `launchd` is definitely the right tool to use. I really like [Lingon](https://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) and [LaunchControl](http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl). The latter also provides a tutorial website for `launchd` at <https://www.launchd.info>. FYI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## launchd

On macOS, [`launchd`](https://www.manpagez.com/man/5/launchd.plist/) is Apple's replacement for `cron`. I don't know what the "official" replacement for `at` is.

See the `StartCalendarInterval` key in [`launchd.plist(5)`](https://www.manpagez.com/man/5/launchd.plist/) to get started.

Comment: launchd is the prefeered way of replacing at see STartCalendarInterval note that  if the machine is asleep then it will run the command on wake so much more like at than crontab